# Cassandra CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I have an enum field that i want to map to a column in cassandra

```
public enum MyEnum {
    Aa,
    Bb,
    Cc,
}
```

and here is how i registered it

```
CodecRegistry myCodecRegistry = new CodecRegistry();
             myCodecRegistry.register(new EnumOrdinalCodec<MyEnum>(MyEnum.class));

            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(cassandraHosts).withPort(cassandraPort).withCodecRegistry(myCodecRegistry).build();
```

i am able to connect to cassandra just fine. Here is a snippet of the model class

```
public class MyModel
{
    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name = "";

    @Column(name="enum")
    private MyEnum enum;

    public MyModel(String i, String n)
    {
        id=i;
        name=n
        enum=MyEnum.Aa;
    }
}
```

and here is how i created the table using CQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
tab 
    (
        name varchar ,
        id varchar, 
        enum varchar, 
        PRIMARY KEY ((id), name));
```

finally, i have my mapping code

```
    manager = new MappingManager(session);
    mapper = manager.mapper(MyModel.class);
    accessor = manager.createAccessor(MyAccessor.class);
```

and here is the `MyAccessor`

```
@Accessor
public interface MyAccessor{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM case WHERE id=? and name=? ALLOW FILTERING;")
    MyModel readByIdAndName(String id,String name);
}
```

so when i try to execute

```
MyModel m = new MyModel("asdasf","qw");
mapper.save(m);
```

i get

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> my.pack.MyEnum]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:56)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException.copy(CodecNotFoundException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:41)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.save(Mapper.java:289)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EnumOrdinalCodec is used to map between int <-> Enum only. As your Enum is based on string, so please use `EnumNameCodec` class instead. Javadoc for these two codec classes are as per below. Hope it helps.

**EnumNameCodec**

> A codec that serializes Enum instances as CQL varchars representing
>   their programmatic names as returned by Enum.name().

**EnumOrdinalCodec**

> A codec that serializes Enum instances as CQL ints representing their
>   ordinal values as returned by Enum.ordinal().

Link to [Javadoc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/extras/codecs/enums/EnumOrdinalCodec.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change you code as follows:

```
/* This is not required
CodecRegistry myCodecRegistry = new CodecRegistry();
         myCodecRegistry.register(new EnumOrdinalCodec<MyEnum>(MyEnum.class));
*/
cluster = Cluster
    .builder()
    .addContactPoint(cassandraHosts)
    .withPort(cassandraPort)
    .build();

class MyEnumCodec: EnumOrdinalCodec<MyEnum> { MyEnumCodec() { super(MyEnum.class) } }

public class MyModel
{
    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name = "";

    @Column(name="enum", codec = MyEnumCodec.class)
    private MyEnum enum;

    public MyModel(String i, String n)
    {
        id=i;
        name=n
        enum=MyEnum.Aa;
    }
}
```