# Enum inner field as parameter of Spring Data @Query statement

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have enum with inner value:

```
public enum Test {
    A("a");

    private String value;
    Test(String value) {
         this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return this.value;
    }
}
```

And I use it as a parameter in Spring Data Cassandra @Query.
Also I added read and write converter to just for parsing "a" -> A and back.
I was expected that if I send A as parameter the query will be generated by converters to. But the query was like "... my_enum = 'A'" instead of 'a'.

I was trying to debug spring sources and found this part of code org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra/1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-1.5.9.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/data/cassandra/convert/MappingCassandraConverter.java:799:

```
    // Cassandra has no default enum handling - convert it either to string
    // or - if requested - to a different type
    if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
        if (requestedTargetType != null && !requestedTargetType.isEnum()
                && getConversionService().canConvert(value.getClass(), requestedTargetType)) {

            return getConversionService().convert(value, requestedTargetType);
        }

        return ((Enum<?>) value).name();
    }
```

Looks like if parameter is enum - converters never be used.
How can i deal with it?
Thank you.

Comment: One obvious work around would be to send `A.toSring()` instead of all `A`s. But i'm guessing you are looking for a more automatic way of conversion...

Comment: I didn't use spring data cassandra before, but if we only use cassandra driver (from datastax), then we need to add custom codec for Enum. Please take a look at the answer I posted before here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996457/cassandra-codecnotfoundexception-codec-not-found-for-requested-operation/48001138#48001138. If possible, please register the custom codec for enum as well in spring-data-cassandra configuration part, and see if it works.

Comment: Jos Angel George:
Sure, this is a most easy way. Just looking for more "spring'able" way.

@Apolozeus:
Actually codec registration works pretty well if using Session.execute(QueryBuilder.(...).build()); I do pretty the same if i need to execute some query instead of spring data repository.
Even more, for enable mapping inside spring data i register ReadingConverter and WrittingConvertera as wrapper on Codec.
And it works fine instead of this case with Enum.

Comment: That's a bug. I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-521.

Comment: @mp911de thanks both, good to know. I will be using cassandra spring data in coming project as well.